# Cross-origin WebSocket request к Spring-приложению

Tags: javascript, java, spring, reactjs, websocket

Делаю UI на React. Разрабатываю это дело через [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) под встроенным сервером. Вношу изменения, вижу результат на странице *localhost:3000*.
Хотелось бы посылать WebSocket-запросы со страницы *localhost:3000* на *localhost:8000*, где у меня запущен Spring WebSocket MessageBroker.
Если копирую код с относительными путями и запускаю страницу под сервлет-контейнером, то всё работает. Но в случае, когда пытаюсь послать запрос с *localhost:3000*, то в консоли браузера вижу, что не получается установить соединение с сервером.

Вот мой WebSocketConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
@Slf4j
@CrossOrigin
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/good").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
    }

}
```

Было бы очень удобно делать UI отдельно от Spring-приложения, но с возможностью разрабатывать React-компоненты с запросами на действующий сервер.
Браузер выдаёт на

```
var socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8080/good');
```

Вот это:

```
Opening Web Socket...
stomp.js:134 Web Socket Opened...
stomp.js:134 >>> CONNECT
accept-version:1.1,1.0
heart-beat:10000,10000
```

А сервер пишет только:

```
o.s.b.w.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter    : Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@525d4c80
o.s.b.w.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter    : Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@525d4c80
```

Comment: А текст ошибок где?

Comment: Ошибок нету, Spring выдаёт только debug-сообщения _Bound/Cleared_. Код контроллера, которому адресовано сообщение, даже не выполняется

Comment: Вы же сами пишите "в консоли браузера вижу, что не получается установить соединение с сервером".

Comment: Это из-за опечатки было, я неправильно localhost написал, когда перепечатывал код в редактор Atom. Теперь коннектится, но результатов так и нету

Comment: Отредактируйте тогда вопрос, чтобы не вводить в заблуждение.

Comment: Уже отредактировал, как только разобрался с опечаткой. Что странно, код контроллера не вызывается

Answer (score 1):

Господа, всё получилось! Сервер был настроен корректно.

На клиенте:

При создании подключения нужно писать полный адрес endpoint'а:

```
const socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8080/good');
```

А подписки и сообщения слать на относительные адреса:

```
stompClient.send("/app/good/add", {}, {description: "desc", price: 2});
```

Полагаю, это связано с тем, что WebSocket создаётся один раз и дальнейшая работа идёт по относительным ссылкам в рамках его endpoint